# How do i break a line in MimeKit.BodyBuilder HtmlBody

Tags: c#, api, email

So I am trying to make a email layout that reads easily. so my intention was getting a break after all the Variables but it doesn't and makes it a very long string.

```
var userEmail = user != null ? CryptographyHelpers.AesDecrypt(user.Email, PahConfig.Key) : null;

        _emailService.Send(new EmailMessage()
        {
           
            Subject = $"Feedback van {user?.FirstName} {user?.LastName}",
            ToAddresses = new List<WiWoUser> { new WiWoUser(){
                Email = CryptographyHelpers.AesEncrypt("MyEmail", PahConfig.Key)
            } },
            Content = new MimeKit.BodyBuilder()
            {
                HtmlBody = $"<html>Feedback: {feedback.feedback} <br>WiWoUserID: {user.WiWoUserID} <br>Email: {userEmail} <br>Telefoonnummer: {user.PhoneNumber}</html>"
            }
        }, false, userEmail);
```

I have the feeling the problem is in the htmlbody. it doesn't reconize the < br > nor the \n. I'm quite lost right now since i can't find anything that solves this.

my expectations:
after every time i requested info i wanted the line to break. that means that if i putted for example the Feedback on line 1 I wanted the UserID on line 2.
what happened:
it doesn't matter if i put < br> or \n in it because it will all be put on line 1

Answer (score 0):

So i took a deep dive into the documentation of the Mimekit bodybuilder and it turned out that i needed to add an @ after the $ to make it pick up the special syntax

```
Content = new MimeKit.BodyBuilder()
            {
                HtmlBody = $@"<html>
                            Feedback: {feedback.feedback} 
                            <br><b>Gegevens van gebruiker:</b>
                            <br>WiWoUserID: {user.WiWoUserID} 
                            <br>Email: {userEmail} 
                            <br>Telefoonnummer: {user.PhoneNumber}
                            </html>"
            }
```